# How I can justify that the residue is -1/2?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I've been  trying to develop this excercise  but can not find a way to justify the fact that the residue is -1/2

Could anyone help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this formula for the residue of a pole of order $n$ at $z=z_0$:

$$
\text{Res}[f,z_0]=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}((z-z_0)^nf(z))
$$

Here, your poles are both order 1 (simple poles), so we have:

$$
\text{Res}[f,0]=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}zf(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{z+1}{z-2}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$

Note of course that this method is only really practical for low-order poles, and doesn't apply at all to essential singularities such as $\exp(1/z)$ at $z=0$.

Comment: There is another theorem that  saidxthat the coefficient is the residue  the residue

Comment: Yes, by definition the residue is the coefficient of the $1/z$ term in the Laurent series, but this method tends to be much easier to use.

Comment: And the residue calculating z = 2, the residue must be the coefficient of 1 / (z-2),  for the same reason mentioned above